# Probability of specific outcome given three probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics

Question:

> Let's say that you are about to pull out 7 marbles from a bag containing red, blue and green marbles. You do not know how many marbles there are in the bag, but that the probability of pulling a red one is $p_a = 0.5$, a blue one is $p_b = 0.3$ and a green one $p_c = 0.2$.
>
> What is the probability that you pull out exactly $4$ red, $1$ blue, and $2$ green?

I tried this:

$B_a(4:,7,0.5)= \binom{7}{4}(0.5)^4(0.5)^3$

$B_b(1:,7,0.3)= \binom{7}{1}(0.3)^1(0.7)^6$

$B_a(2:,7,0.2)= \binom{7}{2}(0.2)^2(0.8)^5$

$B_a*B_b*B_c \approx 0.01859$

$\binom{7}{3}=35$

$0.01859*35 = 0.65065$

But it doesn't seem right. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only give a definite answer to this if you assume each ball is relaced in the bag before drawing the next one. Otherwise the probability of drawing  a ball of any colour would not remain the same over the course of drawing the seven marbles.  With that assumption, the probabilies of drawing any combination of numbers of the three balls follows a [multinomial distribution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

More generally, if there are $\ k\ $ different types of objects that can be obtained on each draw, with probabilities $\ p_1,p_2,\dots,p_k\ $, then the probability of obtaining $\ j_1, j_2, \dots, j_k\ $ objects of types $\ 1,2,\dots,k\ $, respectively, in a total of $\ n\ $ drawings, is
$$ {n \choose j_1 j_2 \dots j_k } p_1^{\,j_1}p_2^{\,j_2}\dots p_k^{\,j_k}\ ,$$
provided $\ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k j_i = n\ $ (or $\ 0\ $ otherwise).  For your probem, $\ k=3\ $, $\ n=7\ $, $\ p_1 = 0.5\ $, $\ p_2 = 0.3\ $, $\ p_3 = 0.2\ $, $\ j_1 = 4\ $, $\ j_2 = 1\ $, and $\ j_3 = 2\ $, so the probability is $\ {7\choose 4\ 1\ 2}\ 0.5^4\,0.3\,0.2^2=\frac{63}{800}\approx\ 0.0788\ .$